# How to create the new bar?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

as you can see in the picture, Windows 10 mobile is using lots of These bars at the bottom. It has Icons (in the picture: "Mailbox", the "Plus" sign etc.) in it and over it are a few Options ("Einstellungen" etc.)which appear when you click the three points.
But how Looks the General form of them in C#?

I went through the whole Internet but I still can´t find out how you create These bars.

[image]

Comment: Try to search for [CommandBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx), *BottomAppBar*.

Comment: Thanks, the CommandBar exists in VS 2015. You can put AppBarButtons on it. But I dont´t get how to add this overlay when pressing the three Buttons button.

Comment: The three dots button is called ellipsis and this 'overlay' is filled with seconday commands, if you haven't defined any secondary commands, you won't get the overlay.

Comment: ok, got it thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a [`CommandBar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar.aspx) class, which is placed in a `Page.BottomAppBar`, especially check its properties like `PrimaryCommands` and `SecondaryCommands`.

You should use a special [`AppBarButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton.aspx) s inside a `CommandBar`, whuch are classic Buttons but with a special rendering, to create it you just set the `Icon` and `Label`.

[Check the guidelines for command bars.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465302.aspx)